# function does not return root node

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to my function return root node of my linked list. Function does work very clearly in operations. But does not return the root node to the main function.
I want to get root node to use it after in main.
Thanks.

```c
struct input* parse_the_input(char str[250]) {
    int spacecount=0;
    int minispacecount;
    int i,j;
    struct input* root;
    struct input* realroot=(struct input*)malloc(sizeof(struct input));
    realroot=root;
    char var[10];
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++) {/*space number in the input string is equal to input number in the string. */
        if(str[i]==' ')
        spacecount++;
    }
    /*deleting "INPUT" part of string in order to read names of inputs as string */
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    str[i]=' ';
    j=6;
    for(i=0;i<spacecount;i++) {
        root=(struct input*)malloc(sizeof(struct input));
        sscanf(str,"%s",var);
        strcpy(root->name,var);
        root->Gate=(struct gate*)malloc(sizeof(struct gate));
        root->Gate->type=0;
        strcpy(root->Gate->name,var);
        if(i==spacecount-1) /*if loop does not break there, program reads rest of string which is full of '\0's. It may cause segmentation fault */
        break;
        minispacecount=0;
        while(minispacecount!=1) { /*filling readed strings with whitespace characters in order to read other string */
            if(str[j]==' ')
            minispacecount++;
            else
            str[j]=' ';
            j++;
        }
        root=root->next;
    }
    return realroot;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fcircuitp=fopen("circuit.txt","r");
    char str[250];
    struct input* root=(struct input*)malloc(sizeof(struct input));
    /* reading circuit file with fgets */
    while( fgets (str, 250, fcircuitp)!=NULL ) {
      if(str[0]=='I') {/* if it is input, then parse the input. */
        root=parse_the_input(str);
        printf("%s",root->name);
      }
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, these three lines makes no sense:

```
struct input* root;
struct input* realroot=(struct input*)malloc(sizeof(struct input));
realroot=root;
```

The first defines `root` but doesn't initialize it. That means it will have an *indeterminate* value. Dereferencing this pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The second line defines `realroot` and initializes it to point to some memory you have allocated.

The third line throws away that recently allocated memory, when you assign the indeterminate value of `root` to `realroot`. That will lead to a *memory leak*, and you returning an invalid pointer from the function.

It seems you misunderstand how pointers and dynamic allocation works. Please take some time to study your text-books more.

Comment: I think realroot took adress of root node. I think even if I change root node, realroot changes automotically.

Comment: @KaanUslu That's like doing something similar to `int a; int b = a; a = 10;` and then expect `b` to also be equal to `10` (which it will not be). That's not how variables work. Again, please take some more time with your text-books.

Comment: Yeah... C is not Excel.